# Raising number to fractional power java

Tags: java, math, pow, exponential

I used the following code:

```
double pow = 3/7;

double num = 85;

System.out.println(Math.pow(num, pow));
```

Expected result:

```
6.71...
```

The output is

```
1.0
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`3/7` is evaluated to 0, since you are dividing two integers, so `Math.pow(num, pow)` becomes `Math.pow(num, 0.0)` which is `1.0`.

Change it to `3.0/7` in order to get a floating point result.