# Java - How to proper rising a number to fractional power?

Tags: java, math

[image]

I have these formulas and I'm looking for a way to translate them into code, but I chew more that I could eat, I really don't know how to raise a value to a fractional power in programming.

I stumbled with these questions:

- [Raising number to fractional power java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877030/raising-number-to-fractional-power-java)
- [Raising a number to a power in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842504/raising-a-number-to-a-power-in-java)

But they don't answer my question

So... what's the proper way to do that?

### EDIT:

**SHOOT!!**

I thought if I ask a simple question with less info I could get a proper answer...

Well... here is my attempt to do what I want to do:

If I follow the answer from the first question I get this:

```
public static void main(String []args)
     {
         double pow = 3.0/2;
         double valA = 20.5;
         System.out.println(Math.pow(valA, pow)/(6 * Math.sqrt(Math.PI)));
     }
```

Result: 8.727796365331747

If I do like I was doing:

```
public static void main(String []args)
     {
         double pow = 3/2;
         double valA = 20.5;
         System.out.println(Math.pow(valA, pow)/(6 * Math.sqrt(Math.PI)));
     }
```

Result: 1.9276477437881674

Again... What's the proper way? and why?

Comment: How does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877030/raising-number-to-fractional-power-java) not answer your question? It in fact *is* the answer.

Comment: If you still need help, you need to show your attempt to use this information (essentially `Math.pow(...)`) and tell us more about how it's not working for you.

Comment: @NAYIR55 like the post linked by Hovercraft, when you have an operation by two integers the result will be an integer, even if the result would be a fraction. The value will be truncate. The different result on your examples is because on your first example you are using a double value (3.0) which produces a double result. The correct way depends of what your doing and how you want the number to be treated, as double or integer.

Comment: I can not answer my own question because it is marked as a duplicate even though I said I found a question already answered

Comment: When calculating `pow=3/2` this is treated as integer division and the result is rounded down to 1.